# hgroup containing an img element validates as HTML5

Tags: html, validation

I've read that an hgroup can only contain Hx elements, however, I have an img wrapped in an anchor inside the hgroup and it still validates. Is this actually allowed according to the spec?

This is a very common header structure and one that I'm currently using:

```
<header>
    <hgroup class="header">
        <h1 class="siteTitle">
            <a href="/">Site Title
                <img src="logo.png" alt="Site Logo" class="logo" />
            </a>
        </h1>
        <h2 class="tagline">Just another WordPress site</h2>
    </hgroup>
    <nav class="menu nav">Nav goes here</nav>
</header>
```

Comment: I've read the same thing, so I'm guessing that any non-inline element is what's intended? For that matter, there's an anchor element inside the hgroup as well, and yet both seem perfectly reasonable.

Comment: Perhaps, but the spec specifically mentions "One or more H level elements.." and does not explicitly state "or inline elements". It would seem to be so since it currently validates though.

Comment: You'll see the exact same description on HTML5Doctor, followed later by an example with an anchor element in it. <shrug>

Answer (score 1):

To answer using your own example, your code is perfectly valid since the hgroup element *contains* only h1 & h2 elemens. By "*contains*", the standard refers to the **direct children** of the hgroup elements: they should be h1-h6. The html inside each heading element should apply to the h1-h6 validation rules. So, following the validator's logic, h1 is allowed to contain anchor elements and the anchor element is allowed to contain an img element; therefore your code is valid html5.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what you've read, but either it or you are confused. `hgroup` can only have `hx` **children**. The `hx` elements can contain exactly the same content as they do when there isn't an hgroup, i.e. *phrasing content* which includes the `img` and `a` elements.

Compare it with the `ul` element - it can only have `li` children, but the `li`s can contain all kinds of elements.